# Apps Script - OOP - Run a class method in HTML sidebar

Tags: javascript, oop, google-apps-script

How to call a class method in the apps script HTML sidebar template?

Apps Script File

```
class SampleClass {
  constructor(){
    this.x = 100;
    this.y = 200;
  }
  
  loadSomeData(){
    Logger.log('some data loaded'); 
    return 'data';
  }
}//class ended

function functionOutsideTheClass(){
  Logger.log('function outside the class'); 
}
```

HTML sidebar File JS

```
$(function(){
  //load 
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onComplete).functionOutsideTheClass();
  // I want to run loadSomeData() function here
});

//callback
var onComplete = function(data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

We can run **functionOutsideTheClass()** function in the HTML JS. In the same manner, Is it possible to run **loadSomeData()** function inside JS or any workaround for it?

Comment: You can't even call `loadSomeData()` outside the class without calling `new SampleClass`

Comment: Hi, I am ok call new Sample class but is it possible to call loadSomeData() along with google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onComplete).... ?

Comment: If you expose it as a function, yes. `const loadSomeDataFunc = ()=> new SampleClass().loadSomeData()`

Answer (score 1):

Expose it as a function:

```
const loadSomeDataFunc = ()=> new SampleClass().loadSomeData()
```